# Map buffer with glMapBuffer, then use pointer in different thread

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to optimize a program that issues all OpenGL ES calls in the main thread. Main performance issue seems to be frequent buffer uploads via glBufferData, more specifically a memcpy inside this function that is done synchronously with the main thread (the buffers a pretty large).

My current plan would be to instead map the buffer in the main thread using glMapBuffer, then send the pointer to a different thread which performs the memcpy, once this thread is finished call glUnmapBuffer again in the main thread. After that, the buffer is used for rendering.

Would this approach work or is it dangerous to use glMapBuffer pointers in a thread that doesn't have the gl context? Or is there a way to ensure no memcpy is performed on the main thread and everything is done on the pipeline thread?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Once you've mapped the buffer then the pointer is a "normal" CPU pointer, so can be used just like any other CPU pointer including cross-thread access.

Just make sure that you've complete any writes and sync the threads before calling `glUnmapBuffer()`.